# Get WordPress Pages in Kirki Select or Text input

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, wordpress-theming

I was using Redux option framework before and using it's feature [data] argument to select page using dropdown to select WordPress page from dropdown, it gives us page ID and we can create anchor links using that page ID in frontend. Now I am trying Kirki customizer framework but I don't find any option to do so, I somehow found that we can do it by 'choices' argument in SELECT option but is being unable to figure out how to do it? Is anyone available to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of Kirki came with solution with Dropdown_Pages control and my problem is solved. Here is example from the kirki documentation:

```
new \Kirki\Field\Dropdown_Pages(
    [
        'settings' => 'dropdown_pages_setting',
        'label'    => esc_html__( 'Dropdown Pages', 'kirki' ),
        'section'  => 'section_id',
        'default'  => 42,
        'priority' => 10,
    ]
);
```

For more information visit: https://docs.themeum.com/kirki/controls/dropdown-pages/

Answer (score 0):

In Kirki, you can use the 'choices' argument to create a dropdown select field in the WordPress customizer. To create anchor links with page IDs, you can follow these steps:

First, ensure that you have Kirki installed and properly configured in your WordPress theme.

Define a section and a control for your dropdown select field in your theme's functions.php or in a separate customizer configuration file:

```
// Replace 'your_theme_prefix' with your actual theme prefix.
Kirki::add_config( 'your_theme_prefix', array(
    'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
    'option_type' => 'theme_mod',
) );

Kirki::add_section( 'page_select_section', array(
    'title' => esc_html__( 'Page Selector', 'your_theme_textdomain' ),
    'panel' => 'your_customizer_panel_id', // Replace with your actual panel ID.
) );

Kirki::add_field( 'your_theme_prefix', array(
    'type'        => 'select',
    'settings'    => 'selected_page',
    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Select a Page', 'your_theme_textdomain' ),
    'section'     => 'page_select_section',
    'default'     => '',
    'choices'     => kirki_get_pages(), // This function retrieves a list of pages.
) );
```

In the above code, replace 'your_theme_prefix' with your actual theme prefix and adjust other settings as needed.

Create a callback function to retrieve the list of pages for the 'choices' argument. You can place this function in your functions.php file or a custom functions file:

```
function kirki_get_pages() {
    $pages = get_pages();
    $page_choices = array();

    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $page_choices[ $page->ID ] = $page->post_title;
    }

    return $page_choices;
}
```

Now, you have a dropdown select field in the WordPress customizer that lists all the pages on your site. Users can select a page, and its ID will be saved in the 'selected_page' theme_mod option.

To create anchor links using the selected page ID on your frontend, you can retrieve the selected page ID using get_theme_mod('selected_page') and then construct your anchor link accordingly:

```
$selected_page_id = get_theme_mod('selected_page');
if (!empty($selected_page_id)) {
    $anchor_link = get_permalink($selected_page_id) . '#your-anchor';
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($anchor_link) . '">Link to Selected Page with Anchor</a>';
}
```

Replace 'your-anchor' with the actual anchor you want to use.

Comment: Can I do it in text field too?